# What kind of sorting algorithm is this? (Code in matlab)

Tags: matlab, sorting, selection

I have a discussion with a teacher. He argues that the following algorithm corresponds to the bubble sort but I insist that it is not. Who is right?

```
clc
clear

a=[0.2 4.333 1/3 5 7]

n=length(a)

for j=n:-1:1
for i=1:j-1
       if a(j)>a(i)
       else
            c=a(i);
            a(i)=a(j);
            a(j)=c;
            a
       end
end
end
```

Comment: Hi Julieth, welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit this question to specifically ask about the code. Let us know how you define bubble sort and how the definition differs from your code example.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like bubble sort as I understand it. It starts from the final element, and compares it to each other element, swapping with the final element until the entire array has been run through, confirming that the largest number is at the end. Bubble sort compares numbers in adjacent pairs.